# Mouse in Vehicle

Tags: camry, body, dashboard

My wife has a 2018 Toyota Camry Hybrid. The car is in excellent shape.

We live in a wooded area and she parks outdoors. She drives the car daily. The issue is that a mouse has taken up residence inside the cabin. We've never actually seen it, but there are torn papers (nesting) and a definite odor. My question is: can anyone give advice on where to look for the critter's point of entry so I can block it somehow? The car sits very low to the ground and is hard to get under, so I'm hoping for a advice on where to start looking.

If I can't find where it is getting in, is this something a mechanic could handle? I am assuming this is a fairly uncommon issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem - but only under the bonnet - of a Pug 307. Set a trap, secured with a tiewrap, and to date am catching a mouse a night (for around a fortnight). No, not the same one... Hope to run out of mice by next week.

So, traps anyway, or use a device which emits a high pitched noise to deter them. Search in all nooks and crannies for any nests, and for now, remove any nesting materials. Only last week, I looked in the small compartment in another car for the jack, and another mouse had used a toilet roll in there for a nest. Very cosy.

Comment: After a few fatalities, mice stopped taking the bait in re-used mousetraps but I knew there were still some around. Humane traps were better, but you must release the mouse at least a mile from your house.

Comment: @WeatherVane - I've been using the same pre-baited trap for ages - 1st 10 mice, I didn't realise it was pre-baited, and the cap stayed on! Yes, homing mice are just another problem. I find the stone attached does slow them down.

Answer (score 1):

Chuck a cat in and leave overnight.

There is the old joke about the Landrover engineers sent to BMW to see how to improve quality. They inspected the production line, looking at all the dimensional checks and tests carried out. Once they got to the end of the line they saw an operative open the door of the BMW coming off  the line and throwing a cat in.

They asked what that was about and were told that the car is checked the next day and if the cat is unconscious then the seals are satisfactory. They then left back to the UK and rushed to Production in the factory to start putting cats in the Landrovers coming off the line.

Next day they went to check to see how the seals were performing and the cats had escaped :) :)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately not a good option I think because: a) it gets down into the 30's (F) at night here now. b) Our cat would probably get annoyed and pee on the upholstery. c) Even if the cat killed the mouse there are probably many others ready to take its place so finding the entry point is probably best.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp well, we had rats in our roof, threw the cat up there for WWIII and cat dealt with them. A **real** farm cat though. One of the benefits of countryside living when the harvest comes in.

Comment: Our cat is mostly an outdoor cat. Except when it gets cold. A true "fair weather friend" - or maybe that's "foul weather friend" in his case. Anyway, he accidentally got locked in the basement once and peed all over some laundry. We had to throw out the clothes. Wouldn't want that in our car.

Answer (score 1):

Use "sticky" traps baited with peanut butter. If you don't want to kill the mouse, vegetable oil will free it from the sticky. I would do it sooner rather than later because he will chew electric wire insulation disabling something.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this applies to your make / model.

https://topclassactions.com/lawsuit-settlements/consumer-products/auto-news/1019074-class-action-toyota-soy-coated-wiring-attracts-vehicle-damaging-rats-can-proceed/